# How to use List in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

how to avoid overwriting value when using a list?
Here is my Problem: i wanted to save to a list the last value i got to use to calculate.... example First time you go to the function and get the resulted value, store that value and the next time you go back you can access that value and then take that value-current value and equal to the Value wanted.

VALUE [A]
VALUE [B]

VALUE [A] - VALUE[B]= VALUE[C]

HOWEVER whats happening is that VALUE [A] Always is being replaced......

```
ListOfLastValue.Add(ResponseTimesOfApp);

// Loop through List with foreach
foreach (string LatestResponseTimes in ListOfLastValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(LatestResponseTimes);
}

// Loop through List with for
for (int i = 0; i < ListOfLastValue.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ListOfLastValue[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: not clear... how would you like the list to look after one call of the function? two? three? give some more data.

Comment: I'm gonna take a wild guess here and say that the objects in the list are mutable.

Comment: i am thinking it because i am creating a new list  List<string> ListOfLastValue = new List<string>(); everytime it goes to that loop, but they way this is organize is through fixtures and each time it goes into that fixture it treats it as another session.... so somehow i need to create it in a class or something that is only called once

Comment: i belive the new instance is created but trying to figure out where i can put this to avoid creating everytime

Answer (score 0):

use SortedList mylist = new SortedList()

with sortedlist the information is stored as a key value pair.

and easily retrievable using key as
string var =   mylist[key];